# get position from value of comma-separated-string mysql

Tags: mysql, database, performance, rdbms

I have a comma separated string like `8,12,17,90`
I have to find the position of the element inside the list with reference to the value I pass in

For E.g

```
Passed In Value 8 =>Outputs 1;
Passed In Value 17=>Outputs 3;
```

Comment: Use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

Comment: What does this have to do with sql?

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

---

**Query #1**

```
select FIND_IN_SET('12', x) from (
select '8,10,12,5' x from dual) t;
```

---

```
| FIND_IN_SET('12', x) |
| -------------------- |
| 3                    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)

Comment: `FIND_IN_SET` has "always" been in MySQL.  Meanwhile, a simpler example is just `SELECT FIND_IN_SET(17, '8,12,17,90');`